# Is it possible to pass property file value to testng.xml as parameter value?

Tags: maven, testng

Is it possible to pass property file value to `testng.xml` as parameter value?

**Example:**

test.properties:

```
browser = FIREFOX
```

testng.xml:

```
parameter name = "browser" value = "${test.browser}"
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes, this is possible by [filtering](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-resources-plugin/examples/filter.html) the `testng.xml` test resource.

Inside your POM, you need to declare a filter poiting to your properties files and override the `<testResources>` to filter the `testng.xml` resource.

```
<build>
  <filters>
    <filter>path/to/test.properties</filter> <!-- relative to location of POM -->
  </filters>
  <testResources>
    <testResource>
      <directory>src/test/resources</directory>
      <includes>
        <include>testng.xml</include>
      </includes>
      <filtering>true</filtering>
    </testResource>
    <testResource>
      <directory>src/test/resources</directory>
      <excludes>
        <exclude>testng.xml</exclude>
      </excludes>
    </testResource>
  </testResources>
  <!-- rest of build section -->
</build>
```

If you properties file contains a key `test.browser`, this will correctly replace the plaholder `${test.browser}` by the value of that key. All of this will happen before the tests are launched so TestNG will see the filtered file with the values replaced.

Note that the above configuration only filters `testng.xml` to avoid filtering too much. You could extend that to filter multiple files.

Comment: Its not working for me. Can you please share some more details, I want to read properties for application.properties file and feed it to testng.xml.

Comment: If not using Maven, is it possible to implement this solution?

Comment: @JavedAhmed, did you manage to get a solution for this?

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible out of the box, but you should be able to something with a [`IAlterSuiteListener`](http://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html#ialtersuite) where you'll replace values by what you want.

Comment: Hi @juherr, are you able to shed more light on this?

Comment: @TinasheChinyanga In the IAlterSuiteListener, you'll have access to the XmlSuite object. There, you can iterate on the parameters and modify them depending on your logic (in the sample, it could be a pattern on the read value in order to find the key and replaced by the value of the properties file)