# How to assign the parameter value in TestNG Xml from properties file

Tags: selenium-webdriver, testng

is it possible for set the parameter value i.e.  from properties file ?

There are 200 Test cases, I want to read the browser value from the properties file and pass it TestNG XML suite. The value chrome should be read from the properties file and start the execution

Comment: This link has the approach -   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38634335/is-it-possible-to-pass-property-file-value-to-testng-xml-as-parameter-value

Comment: Thanks, it helped me to resolve the problem I am facing.